# Преобразование матрицы из [10,] в [20,]

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

Проблема заключается в том, что у меня есть матрица 10х1 и ее надо преобразовать в матрицу 20х1 или любую другую, пробовал использовать метод np.reshape и resample, но выдает ошибку

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (20,)

Сам код:

```
import numpy as np
import samplerate

df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep=",",  usecols= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(df.loc[1])
xnew = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
resample_signal = np.reshape(df.values[1,:],20)
y = samplerate.resample(resample_signal, 2, 'sinc_best')  
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(xnew, y, label = 'Передискретизированный сигнал')
plt.show()
```

Ссылка на файл 1.csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GiFJWky6IfLhjbJlBbS7TDcGIHFErqyo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `resample` вроде должен работать, а вот `reshape` не будет работать, он только форму матрицы меняет, а число элементов то же остаётся

Comment: resample не является атрибутом numpy

Comment: `scipy.signal.resample`

Comment: ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis. Другую ошибку выдает.

Comment: преобразовать не проблема. вопрос в том, какие значения вы хотите видеть в дополнительных ячейках?

Comment: те значения, которые есть в csv файле, если по ним построить график, то получаем определенный сигнал, но проблема в том, что этих сигналов там около 700. И нужно, чтобы эти значения не искажали сигналы, а дополняли матрицу без нарушений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться методом `numpy.pad`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
arr = np.pad(arr, (5,5))
# arr: [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Чем заполнять ячейки, решайте сами. документация по numpy.pad вам в помощь